# ¿Cómo alinear al centro las columnas en un gráfico de tipo Polar en highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estas son las opciones del gráfico que estoy intentando crear (Rosa de los vientos, Wind-Roses con Highcharts)

**Opciones**

```
options={
                data:{
                    table: 'wind_rose',
                    startRow: 1,
                    endRow: 17,
                    endColumn: categories.length,

                },
                chart: {
                    //
                    polar: true,
                    type: 'column',
                    //renderTo: 'chart-container'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                pane: {
                    size: '85%'
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 100,
                    layout: 'vertical'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    //min: 0,
                    //max: 360,
                    //type: "",
                   // tickInterval: 22.5,
                   // categories: categories,
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                   /* labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return categories[this.value / 22.5] + '°';
                        }
                    }*/
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    endOnTick: false,
                    showLastLabel: true,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency (%)'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value + '%';
                        }
                    },
                    reversedStacks: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        shadow: false,
                        groupPadding: 0,
                        pointPlacement: 'on',
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        states: {
                            select: {
                                color: null,
                                borderColor: 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

El resultado del gráfico con las opciones anteriores es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos ingresados son correctos sin embargo el gráfico muestra las columnas fuera de la circunferencia, el resultado debería ser algo parecido a esto:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-wind-rose/

Comment: Así no se Pregunta. Lee [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)